# Web based forecasting tools

Tags: regression, time-series

We want to add a forecasting tool to our website -- it would draw off a historical database and users can choose the model (Box Jenkins, Simple Linear Regression, etc.), confidence interval and play what-if.   Is anyone aware of such package we can plug into our website?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at AUTOBOX at http://www.autobox.com as it satisfies all of your needs and a lot more including very sophisticated regression analysis of time series data. I am one of the developers of the system.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/strategico/

Strategico - A free software for long term time series prediction and forecasting

Comment: I tried one of my favorite data challenges 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,1,5 on the Strategico link you provided and found that it did not pick up the clearly visually obvious pattern and identify the anomaly. It gave a forecast of 5,5,5,5,5,5,... which did not pass our test for identifying and adjusting for outliers.  See Ruey Tsay's work on outlier detection(see http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf) for the importance of handling these issues.